# Ubuntu Stuck at the Startup Screen; how to get it working?

Tags: updates, login, boot-failure, startup

After since I cancelled the updates in the last stage `(making changes to database<setting AppArmour>)` and hard-rebooting my laptop with ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) is stuck at the startup screen :- `The screen just before the username/password prompt` with `blinking dots`. I have tried to run the `previous versions` but with no help.

I can't even login to terminal.

Please help; I don't want to reinstall or loose my data.

---

Edit:- I've been able to drop to the root shell from the recovery mode; is there a way I can get the things normal?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: yes i tried recovery mode and tried to fix broken packages but even after waiting for 1 hour or got no help.

Comment: This Question covers many black screen issues http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: @ChrisCarter I don't agree with it being a duplicate of that one. This is probably a specific broken package causing a boot failure. Ankit could provide the last lines of failure from ˋ/var/log/apt/term.logˋ for more information on what exactly went wrong.

Comment: @ChrisCarter Also, this is not a black screen at all. The screen with the dots is the Ubuntu splash screen. Pressing Esc or F2 at this screen will reveal messages documenting what has happened as Ubuntu has tried to start up; some may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem - in my case, the `.profile` file had become corrupted. Move this to `.profile_old` and try logging in again. The only other problem I am aware of that can cause this is a bad Xorg conifguration - you might check that that's all correct too if the first suggestion doesn't help.